# A group has a Finite maximal group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ has a finite maximal subgroup then what can I say about G ?  Is it finite or infinite or finitly generated group ?

Answer (score 1):

A [Tarski monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) is infinite, but all of its proper, non-trivial subgroups have order $p$, for a fixed prime $p$. So all proper, non-trivial subgroups are maximal and finite.

However, a group $G$ with your conditions is definitely finitely generated, as it is generated by the finite set of elements of the given maximal subgroup, plus any single element outside it.